# Why is my font not displaying correctly for Spring Tool Suite Dashboard on MacOS?

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

On both of my Macs I'm having an odd font display problem for the Dashboard which loads the spring.io website.   I've tried multiple versions of STS and two different Macs running Sierra. If I look at other sites via the dashboard, generally it displays fine and if I use an external browser like Safari or Chrome the site displays correctly.  It is only in the Dashboard that this problem exists. Further, this problem does not exist if I go to preferences/dashboard and select use old dashboard.  The styling goes back to the old method but the font problem is not there at least.

[image: Example of Font Display - expected display of English US]

Comment: wow, that looks strange... what language settings do you have on your OSX machine? Anything special? I am running on OSX Sierra, too, and the dashboard looks just fine. Therefore wondering what the difference might be.

Comment: I have the same issue on MacOS Sierra

Comment: I am using English on both Macs and both are running MacOS Sierra.  Perhaps given others with same OS are having this issue, this is MacOS Sierra specific and the dashboard setting is the work around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Switch to old dashboard from preference menu.

[image]